# How to prevent href tag showing in Whatsapp

Tags: php, whatsapp

I have the following script which sends response to Whatsapp:

```
 $respondotuser.= "\n\n Order has been processed, 
                   Kindly click <a href=\"https://google.com\">Here</a> 
                   to make payment online or pay 
                  directly to waiter amount ₦ "
                  .number_format($totalbelanja);
$respondotuser.= "\n\n Pls show payment confirmation to 
                  our waiters or delivery Staff ";
```

When it sends it, it shows the `href` tags in Whatsapp. How can I prevent it from showing the `href` tags?

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why make a tag? Direct link is ok.

Comment: By not trying to use HTML in there in the first place … The message is supposed to be _text_. It will automatically parse _URLs_ contained in the message into clickable links, but you can not use your own custom HTML.